# Integral containing Bessel Function

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

**Problem:**

Evaluate in terms of bessel functions:

$$\int_{}^{} x^{-2} J_2(x)  dx $$

**Attempt**
Rewriting the integrasl as: $\int_{}^{} x^{-1}*x^{-1}J_2(x) dx $ then using Integration By Parts to get:
$$\int_{}^{}x^{-2} J_2(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}J_1 -\int_{}^{} \frac{1}{x^3} J_1 dx $$

Integration by parts again:

$$\int_{}^{}x^{-2} J_2(x) = -x^{-2} J_1 +x^{-3}J_0 -3\int_{}^{} x^{-4} J_0 dx $$

Now, I am not sure how to continue. Is there another simplification? Or another approach that can express the integral without using another integral?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bessel functions have nice properties, so it is usually not hard to find closed-form solutions of integrals that contain them. Let:

$$I=\int{J_2(x)\over x^2}dx \tag 1$$

We use the property that can be found [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Partial_Differential_Equations_(Walet)/10%3A_Bessel_Functions_and_Two-Dimensional_Problems/10.05%3A_Properties_of_Bessel_functions):

$$ xJ_2(x)=2J_1(x)-xJ_0(x) \tag 2$$
$$ J_2(x)={2J_1(x)-xJ_0(x) \over x} \tag 3$$

Inserting $(3)$ into $(1)$ we obtain:

$$ I= 2 \int {J_1(x) \over x^3}dx - \int {J_0(x) \over x^2}dx \tag 4$$

Next, we use the property that can be found [here](https://solitaryroad.com/c678.html) (section **Indefinite integrals**):

$$\int{J_1(x) \over x^m} dx = -{J_1(x) \over mx^{m-1}}+{1\over m} \int{J_0(x)\over x^{m-1}}dx \tag 5$$

In our case $m=3$, so we get:

$$I = -{2J_1(x) \over 3x^2} - {1\over 3} \int {J_0(x) \over x^2}dx \tag 6$$

From the same link and under the same section, we use the property:

$$ \int {J_0(x)\over x^n}dx = {J_1(x)\over (n-1)^2 x^{n-2}}- 
 {J_0(x) \over (n-1) x^{n-1}}-{1\over (n-1)^2}\int{J_0(x)\over {x^{n-2}}}dx \tag 7$$

So for $n=2$ we get:

$$ I = -{2 J_1(x)\over 3x^2}-{J_1(x)\over3}+{J_0(x)\over3x}+{1\over3}\int J_0(x)dx \tag 8 $$

This is a well-known integral. If you look [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/21/01/01/) you will find:

$$\int J_0(x)dx={\pi x \over 2}H_0(x)J_1(x)+{x\over 2}(2-\pi H_1(x))J_0(x)+const \tag 9 $$

where $H_0$ and $H_1$ are the [Struve](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StruveFunction.html) functions. So the final solution to your integral is:

$$ I = \Bigg( {\pi x \over 6}H_0(x)-{2\over3x^2}-{1\over3} \Bigg)J_1(x)- 
 \Bigg( {\pi x \over 6}H_1(x)-{x\over3}-{1\over3x} \Bigg)J_0(x) +const \tag{10}$$

which I verified using [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=D%5B%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29pi*Divide%5Bx%2C6%5D*StruveH%5C%2891%290%5C%2844%29%20x%5C%2893%29-Divide%5B2%2C3*Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D-Divide%5B1%2C3%5D%5C%2841%29J1%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29-%5C%2840%29pi*Divide%5Bx%2C6%5D*StruveH%5C%2891%291%5C%2844%29%20x%5C%2893%29-Divide%5Bx%2C3%5D-Divide%5B1%2C3x%5D%5C%2841%29J0%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D) (check alternate forms).

Comment: (5) is a really nice property & form (8) is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it helps :D